# Postgresql Select a column or other under the same alias according to the value of a third column

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, case

I have a database whose schema can be simplified in this way: a product table, and two tables containing values to enrich the description of a product. I would like to make a SELECT query allowing me to display the product id followed by a column containing a value.
This value can be selected in the attribute_value_1 table if the product is of type 'Type1' or in the attribute_value_2 table if the product is of type 'Type2'.

**Table product**

| product_id | type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | type1 |
| 2 | type2 |

**Table attribute_value_1**

| id | product_id | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | XXXXX |

**Table attribute_value_2**

| id | product_id | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | ZZZZZ |

So in the following example, the result of the query should be :

**Result**

| product_id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | XXXXX |
| 2 | ZZZZZ |

Do you know how I can proceed?

Answer (score 1):

you can use two left joins with each attribute table and then using coalesce() function , get the value from those table thatmatched:

```
select P.product_id , coalesce(att1.value, att2.value) value
from product p 
left join attribute_value_1 att1
   on p.product_id = att1.product_id and p.type = 'type1'
left join attribute_value_1 att2
   on p.product_id = att2.product_id and p.type = 'type2'
```